# Multiple resource calls with promises in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, ngresource

I am developing a simple AngularJS application which authenticates a user and displays a list of transactions associated to the user. In addition, there is a dropdown which allows the user to filter the transactions by year. The combobox model is an array of values that I retrieve from my API through an AngularJS resource, but only after I have retrieved the current user. This is the code:

```
    //retrieve the user
    UserManagement.getCurrentUser().then(function (user) {
        //retrieve the transactions
        $scope.transactions = Transactions.query({ 
                                                  userid: user.UserName, 
                                                  status: $scope.status 
                                                 }); 
        //retrieve the array for the dropdown
        //and return a promise
        return TimeFilters.get({ 
                                userid: user.UserName, 
                                status: $scope.status, 
                                timefilter: 'years' 
                               });
     }).then(function (years) {
             //set a scope variable to the array to bind in the view
             $scope.timefilters.years = years;
             console.debug(years);
             //set also the currently selected year
             $scope.timefilters.currentYear = $scope.timefilters.years[0];
     })
```

Even though I learned promises today and maybe I misunderstood something, this code seems straightforward.

The problem is that when I try to assign `currentYear` to the first element of `timefilters.years`, the assignment fails because the array is still empty, even if it shouldn't be, as I am trying to assign in the `.then` function. The result is that the dropdown is populated with the years, but no year is selected.

What did I misunderstand here?

BTW, the resource calls return the expected data, so that is not the problem.

EDIT: just after posting I changed the return statement in the first `then` to:

```
return TimeFilters.get({...}).$promise
```

and now it works as espected. But I thought that $resource.get was meant to return a promise already. I am really confused. Could someone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular $resources docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) has the answer:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data.

And:

> The Resource instances and collection have these additional
>   properties:
>
> $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created
>   this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or
>   collection object, updated with data from server.

So when calling $resource.get(), do expect to get something like a reference to an empty `Object` or `Array`. Only with `$resource.get().$promise` you will recieve the deisred promse object.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that my approach is the only one for dealing with resource retrieval synchronization , right? (apart from using callbacks, that I don't like very much)

Comment: I was using `$resource.get().$get()` and it issued duplicate calls. 
Use of `$resource.get().$promise` solved the issue. Thanks !